# DBD::mysql installation on Catalina/Big Sur fail with 'EXTERN.h' file not found?

Tags: macos, perl, mysql-connector, macos-catalina, dbd

I install DBD::mysql on Catalina preparing:

```
perl Makefile.PL --testpassword=s3kr1t --testhost=localhost --testport 3306 --testuser=test --libs="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.12/lib -lmysqlclient"
```

after run 'make' I get an error:

```
/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/DBIXS.h:22:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
```

s. [DBD::mysql::INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBD-mysql/view/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at EXTERN.h:

```
$ find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools -name EXTERN.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/EXTERN.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/EXTERN.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/EXTERN.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/EXTERN.h
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/EXTERN.h
```

check your perl version:

$ perl -v

```
This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 4 (v5.18.4) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

the right header is:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/EXTERN.h
```

Use the correct OSX header so it work:

```
perl Makefile.PL --testpassword=s3kr1t --testhost=localhost --testport 3306 --testuser=test --libs="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/lib -lmysqlclient" --cflags='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/zstd/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/include/mysql'
```

PS, don't forget create mysql user 'test' with all privileges :-)

See details at:

- [cpan installation DBD::mysql problem on macos + problem resolution](https://github.com/perl5-dbi/DBD-mysql/issues/161)
- [“Fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found” while installing Perl modules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55305353/1514029)
- [Missing headers in macOS 10.15 (Catalina)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373316/missing-headers-in-macos-10-15-catalina)

**UPGRADE for OSX 11.1 - Big Sur:**

If I take the way above, I get at first the Error:

```
./dbdimp.h:20:10: fatal error: 'DBIXS.h' file not found
#include <DBIXS.h>  /* installed by the DBI module                        */
```

The fix is, extend the perl Makefile.PL to:

```
perl Makefile.PL --testpassword=s3kr1t --testhost=localhost --testport 3306 --testuser=test --libs="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/lib -lmysqlclient" --cflags='-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/zstd/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.25_1/include/mysql -I/Library//Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI'
```

The next problem is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h', needed by `mysql.xsi'.  Stop.
```

Why this? The default installation of DBI on Big Sur is broken!

After downloading the current DBI archive DBI-1.643.tar.gz and reinstall DBI the DBD::mysql make run complete!

Now I must make a break :-) after 2 hours try and error!!!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to compile on Big Sur using:

```
cpanm DBD::mysql --configure-args="--cflags=-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/\ -I/usr/local/mysql/include/\ -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types\ -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro" --force
```

I had to disable the two warnings to get a full compile, the next one was indeed the the no rule error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/Driver_xst.h', needed by `mysql.xsi'.  Stop.
```

This was solved by first doing:

```
cpanm DBI --force
```

And the doing the original:

```
cpanm DBD::mysql --configure-args="--cflags=-I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.30/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/\ -I/usr/local/mysql/include/\ -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types\ -Wno-compound-token-split-by-macro" --force
```

Then there was one remaining issue for getting Bugzilla to work, which is solved here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1588175